# Chart.js legend alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm creating a pie chart using Chart.JS tool. So far i have achieved to create a 2 pie charts. [image]

The issue is that it shifts the second pie chart to the left. I have used legend.position = ** left**.

But when i try to modify the position to **bottom** , first pie chart shrinks [image]

HTML CODE

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="col-lg-12 pie-chart" style="">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class='col-12 chart-container' ><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
                    <div class='col-12 chart-container' ><canvas id="subChart"></canvas></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
body > .pie-chart{
    padding:10px;margin-top:60px;height:32vh;background-color:white;
}
body > .pie-chart >.chart-container{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#myChart {
    margin-top: 90px;
    height:180px;
}
#subChart {   
    margin-top: 30px;
    height:180px;
}
```

This is my js code to create pie chart.

```
 createGraph: function (canvasElement, data, backgroundColor, labels, clickCallback, renderCallBack) {
                var config = {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: {
                        datasets: [{
                                data: data,
                                backgroundColor: backgroundColor
                            }],
                        labels: labels
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: false,
                        legend: {
                            position: 'left',
                            onHover: function (e) {
                                e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                            },
                            labels: {
                                fontSize: 13,
                                fontStyle: 'bold'
                            },
                        },
                        title: {display: false},
                        animation: {animateScale: false, animateRotate: false},
                        hover: {
                            onHover: GraphController.hoverChart
                        }
                    }
                };
                if (clickCallback) {
                    config.options.legend.onClick = clickCallback; //click on labels
                    config.options.onClick = clickCallback; // click on pie
                }
                if (renderCallBack) {
                    config.options.legend.onRender = renderCallBack;
                }
                if (canvasElement.id = "subChart") {
                    // set subchart height and width so that the chart chart doesn't blur
                    $('#subChart').attr('height', $("#myChart").attr('height'));
                    $('#subChart').attr('width', $("#myChart").attr('width'));
                }
                return new Chart(canvasElement, config);
    }
```

Can anybody point out me what i am missing out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to check something... can you make the margin-top of the #myChart 30px as well and see if they become the same size? Let me know so I can make a suggestion.

Comment: Hi,Architect. Thanks for the response, I updated to **#myChart** to 30px;. Didn't work out, Still the same

Comment: Did they become the same size? Just remove the margin top for both of them and add width as well. width:180px; height:180px; and see if this makes their size the same.

Comment: when i use width:180px and remove margin-top for both the pie charts, only Labels get displayed.

Comment: Give me a minute, let me try this on my local.

Comment: The problem is in the **if (canvasElement.id = "subChart") { ... }** code. Comment that  code and see if the charts are the same size. If so, let me know.

Comment: after commenting too. Charts remains the same..

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, I think there is no styling problem here. I think the issue is when you put the labels at the bottom, on the first chart, which has 3 labels, they break into 2 lines as the second one that has 2 labels stays in 1 line. So as the canvas is generated it fits the chart to the space available.

Please leave only 1 label on both charts and see if they are the same size then.